# ERROR When Accessing a Local Website from another Computer on Same Network

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-7, localhost

I have a Visual Studio project that I have setup through IIS. I can access that website locally (computer A) via chrome with no issues. I do not have to have VS open or debug the project.

I have gone ahead and setup my IIS to have the following bindings...

1. type: http / host name: work.local / port: 80 / ip address: *
2. type: http / host name: / port: 80 / ip address: "my computers IP address"

I used to be able to access the website from another computer (computer B) on the same network without problems, but now nothing. If I enter the computer A's ip address on computer B via chrome; I get the IIS7 welcome screen/image. If i proceed to add the rest of the URL, I get a "This site can't be reached 'computer A's IP Address' refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFSUED".

I also have port 80 setup to allow all incoming connections.

Any idea's or things I can try to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches to isolate the issue.

- Please add a binding with hostname as blank,IP address * and port 80 - **with this binding,you should be able to access the site using http://localhost, http://machinename, http://fqdnmachinename **
- Also check your firewall.Make sure firewall does not have any rule or completely turn off firewall and verify
- Try to access the with fully qualified name(FQDN)
- Check Event logs for system and application events
- Capture network trace in the chrome or IE developer toolbar. May be you are getting a redirection from website.

You can also verify if your site is listening on all IP address on port 80 with following command

`netstat -ano | find ":80"`

This command should list process with I'd 4 listening on port 80 .

Hope this helps!

Comment: The binding you requested I add is already there. I turned off my firewall like you mentioned. Still no luck. I checked google chromes console and all that reads is "GET http://myipaddress/PSM/login.aspx net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" FYI I also tried this command `netstat -ano" and it correctly shows process with ID 4 listening on port80.

Comment: I did realize that if i enter localhost in the address bar on my local machine the website loads, but if i explicitly type the ip address i get the same error as I have mentioned above.

Comment: do you mean you can work with localhost but not the ipaddress ?

Comment: Now it works on my local machine (Disregard the previous comment, it was not working but now it is). I can access my local site from my local machine either way: xxx.xxx.x.xxx/login.aspx or localhost/login.aspx. I still can't get access from outside my local machine on my local network. When I use xxx.xxx.x.xxx/login.aspx on my local machine it does load but says "not secure".

Comment: Could you add the screenshot ? your application has a redirect rule or code which redirect requests to https ?